# How to connect to mysql using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on my php as I want to connect to the mysql database using PDO. I have stored the username, password and database in the config file, but I have got a problem with connecting to the mysql database because I keep getting an error.

When I try this:

```
<?php

//Connect to the database
include('config.php');

$smtps = $link->query('SELECT * FROM sent');
$smtps->execute();
$db = $smtps->get_result();

print($db);
?>
```

I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   PDOStatement::get_result() in
>   /home/username/public_html/test_pdo.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in /home/username/public_html/test_pdo.php on line 17

Here is the line 17:

```
$db = $smtps->get_result();
```

Here is the config:

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbtablename');
//$errflag = false;
$link = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.'', DB_USER, DB_PASS);

?>
```

Can you please show me an example how do you connect to mysql database using PDO when you stored the username, password and database name in config.php?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe because `get_result` is not a [PDO method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ?

Comment: YvesLeBorg: Maybe you are right, so how I can get the results using PDO method?

Comment: The only thing that work is if I use this `$smtps = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM sent");
$servers = $smtps->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`. but I dont feel the mysqli method is secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `get_result()` is not a PDO method.

In this situation you should just use `fetch()` ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)) if you just want the first result or `fetchAll()` ([link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)) if you want an array of the results

Try this:

```
$smtps = $link->query('SELECT * FROM sent');
$result = $smtps->fetchAll();

print($result);
```

You only need to use the excute() when using parameters in your select:

```
SELECT * FROM sent where id = ?
```

would be

```
$smtps = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM sent where id = ?');
$smtps->execute([$id]);
$result = $smtps->fetch();

print($result);
```

Comment: I think `$link->query` with a parameter should be `$link->prepare`.

Comment: @Oli Girling Thank you very much for this. I am not aware that the `get_result` is not a pdo method. So when I want to use the variable `$MessageId`, how I can use it to find the data I want using pdo?

Comment: @Oli Girling Example: `$emailTrackers_sql = $link->query('SELECT * FROM sent WHERE email_id = ?');
$emailTrackers_sql->bind_param('s', $messageID);
$emailTrackers_sql->execute();`

Comment: @NigelRen, your right, somehow I missed that, fixed on the answer.

Comment: @OliGirling When I try this `$emailTrackers_sql = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM sent WHERE email_id = ?');
$emailTrackers_sql->bind_param('s', $messageID);
$emailTrackers_sql->execute();` it will give me this `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()` . Any idea?

Comment: `bind_param()` is not a PDO method either. 
Replace this -> `$emailTrackers_sql->bind_param('s', $messageID);` with this -> 
`$emailTrackers_sql->bindParam(1, $messageID, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: @OliGirling Thank you. I got it working at the end so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If u use query method u can without execute method get result as as below cod

```
include('config.php');

$result = $link->query('SELECT * FROM sent')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_results` is not a method of the [**PDO**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) class. If you want to fetch data from the database in this case, use `fetchAll()` method of the query object.

```php
<?php

//Connect to the database
include('config.php');

$smtps = $link->query('SELECT * FROM sent');
$smtps->execute();
$db = $smtps->fetchAll();

print($db);
?>
```

Hope that helps.